# I cant add on click method to print button in print screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanna add href attribute to my button in print screen but i cant.

```
function PrintOrder(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/PaymentTracking/PrintOrderNewAdvance',
                data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    Print(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        }

        function Print(html) {
            var div = document.getElementById('printarea');
            var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
            newWin.document.open();
            newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + html + '</body></html>');
            //newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="setTimeout(function () { window.print(); }, 1)">' + html + '</body></html>');
            newWin.document.close();
            //setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 100);
        }
```

Here is my Print method.

[image: and this is my print screen]

I wanna add href attribute to my Print button below but how to I cant even reach it.

Comment: create a demo for it

Comment: Your screenshot shows the *print preview dialog* opened by your code `window.print()`.  There's no "button" on what you've shown as it's part of the browser's print feature.

Comment: You have `html` as a string - change it before you add it to your new window.  though it's unclear what you think the "print button" is that you want to change as there don't appear to be any print buttons on the preview and the *"Yazdir"* button isn't part of your page.